# Serilog not logging with supervisor

Tags: linux, supervisord, serilog

I try to make serilog working with my app executed via supervisord - unfortunately, it does not work so far.

I made a couple of tests and was able to isolate the problem. Both of commands below were executed on root account.

**Does not log to file**

`su -s /bin/bash -c "cd /home/user/test/; dotnet test.dll" - root`

**Works (text is written to a log file and console)**

`dotnet test.dll`

The tests were performed on CentOS with SELinux turned off. The configuration in appsettings.json is the same.

Any suggestions on what else can I test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turned out that environment variable was not set.

In supervisor config I was missing

```
environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
```